# Special Emoji doesn't present correctly in device

Tags: ios, emoji

I use unicode("\uE43B") in `UILabel`, the weird thing is it works in simulator but not works in real device. The code is below:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:label];
label.text = @"The emoji is:\uE43B";
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

The result runs in simulator:

[image]

When I run it in my device(iPhone6 9.3.2), it shows a rectangle character.

[image]

I have search Google for `\uE43B` and [this site](https://codepoints.net/U+e43b) says:

> This is a Private Use codepoint. That is, it is deliberately not assigned to any character. It was added to Unicode in version 1.1 and belongs to the block Private Use Area.

But I still don't understand how simulator works, some apps like wechat also can show the emoji.

Comment: This issue is only with \uE438 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely are using a custom font on your Mac that you are not using on your iPhone. As you note, this is not a proper Unicode code point. It's a private-use character. Those code points can be added to fonts if they desire.

The iOS Simulator is just a Mac application that includes a Mac-compatible version of UIKit. Things available on your Mac will be available to the Simulator, even if they are not available on iOS devices.

The particular character you're referencing is [U+1F38F (CARP STREAMER)](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf). 
I don't know why you have it mapped to U+E43B. It's possible you have an Asian font that has this as a legacy code point (a common use of the private use characters).

Comment: Thanks, it works with `label.text = @"The emoji is:\U0001f38f";`. I'm curious to know how did you find the U+1F38F so quickly with a wrong unicode and a .